# How to read jsonl file and normalize json column

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

I have to read jsonl file in python and normalize column consist of json.
I succesfully read with pandas

```
    df = pd.read_json('file.jsonl', lines=True)
```

and I have information in one of my columns like

**column2**

```
{"key1" : "kvalue1", "key2" : "kvalue2" }
```

I can normalize them seperately but I don't know why it doesn't work for all the data.
I do normalization for this column like this

```
normdata = pd.json_normalize(df['column1'])
```

it works like this but when I want to do for all the dataset it doesn't work. I thought maybe problem lies in the type of data so I checked them. **df['column2']** is **series** and **df** itself is **DataFrame**. I converted DataFrame to series to check but it didn't work.

The data example :

```
{"column1" : "value1", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue1", "key2" : "kvalue2" } }
{"column1" : "value2", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue3", "key2" : "kvalue4" } }
{"column1" : "value3", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue5", "key2" : "kvalue6" } }
```

I want to seperate 'column2' informations like 'key1', 'key2' in seperate columns using pandas

Do you have nice idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON and expected results?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn Of course. Question is edited

Comment: I believe you would have better results if you provided a coded version of the JSON and coded expected results. Sending links is pretty frowned upon

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I edited the post. Sorry for inconvenience. Is that clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = [{"column1" : "value1", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue1", "key2" : "kvalue2" } },
        {"column1" : "value2", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue3", "key2" : "kvalue4" } },
        {"column1" : "value3", "column2" : {"key1" : "kvalue5", "key2" : "kvalue6" } }]

# Generate the dataframe for the array items in
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
record = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Append it to the dataframe
dataframe =  pd.concat([dataframe,record], ignore_index=True)

# Renaming columns of the dataframe
col = {"column1":"column1","column2.key1":"key1","column2.key2":"key2"}
df = dataframe.rename(columns = col)[[*col.values()]]

df


OUTPUT:     column1  key1    key2
       0    value1  kvalue1 kvalue2
       1    value2  kvalue3 kvalue4
       2    value3  kvalue5 kvalue6
```

Also, if you wish to directly convert the JSON file even you can use below function:

```
import json
def read_json(filename: str) -> dict:
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
    except:
        raise Exception(f"Reading {filename} file encountered an error")

    return data

def create_dataframe(data: list) -> pd.DataFrame:

    # Declare an empty dataframe to append records
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

    # Looping through each record
    for d in data:

    # Normalize the column levels
        record = pd.json_normalize(d)
    # Append it to the dataframe
        dataframe =  pd.concat([dataframe,record], ignore_index=True)

    return dataframe


# Read the JSON file as python dictionary
data = read_json(filename="./demo.json")

#*data=data[insert parameter according to your json data]*
dataframe = create_dataframe(data=data['data'])

# Renaming columns of the dataframe
col = {"column1":"column1","column2.key1":"key1","column2.key2":"key2"}
df = dataframe.rename(columns = col)[[*col.values()]]

df
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do something similar to it. Could you check reading same data from the file. I have big data like this data and reading from .jsonl file I think there is the problem in my situation

Comment: @MammadliAnar I have try to update, let me know if I can help you more.